# Different elements in a factor ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Studying for my algebra exam I found the following problem, which I'm not sure how to solve

> Let $f = X^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{F}_5[X]$, $R = \mathbb{F}_5[X]/\langle f \rangle$ and $\alpha = X + \langle f \rangle \in R$. Show that $-1$, $2\alpha$ and $-2\alpha$ are different elements in $R$.

I know that two cosets $x + \langle f \rangle$, $y + \langle f \rangle$ are equal $\iff$ $x - y \in \langle f \rangle$.

So when proving that $2\alpha$ and $-2\alpha$ are different I need to prove that $2X - (-2X) = 4X \notin \langle f \rangle$? I'm not quite sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Looks OK! And any nonzero multiple of $f$ clearly has degree at least $2$, so $4X \not\in \langle f \rangle$. This problem is really just checking that you understand all of the definitions.

Comment: In fact you can go further and show that the polynomials of degree $< 2$ are a complete system of reps for the cosets (for the opposite direction uses the division algorithm to show that $g$ is equivalent to its remainder mod $f$ or, equivalently, uses the rewrite rule $\,X^2 = -1\,$ to eliminate all powers of $\,X\,$ greater than $1$ in $\,g.\ $